# Cocoa interface to GEDCOM file

Tags: cocoa, macos, open-source, genealogy, gedcom

The only full-fledged GPL Cocoa editor for GEDCOM 5.5 files (GenerationX) was last released in 2003: http://sourceforge.net/projects/generationx/
It looks unstable under Snow Leopard and would badly need a revamp.

Someone recently posted a proof-of-concept application (unrelated to GenerationX) on Google Code, but it looks like an unmaintained project:
http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-gedcom/

Is there any Cocoa developer interested in genealogy and willing to resurrect any of these projects? Or any other projects with a decent release cycle I am not aware of?

The Mac genealogy software market is dominated by pricy and feature-bloated proprietary solutions. A no-nonsense open source GEDCOM-compliant framework for Mac OS would be a blessing.

Comment: That's more of a rentacoder.com question. :/

Comment: "any other projects with a decent release cycle I am not aware of?"
this bit is not

Comment: Does it have to be Cocoa, or does it just need to work on the Mac?  Would you be interested in a Java app that ran on the Mac?

Comment: Jay, I am not a big fan of Java apps on Mac OS in general. I have seen this one on SF:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/genj/ but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out [GRAMPS](http://gramps-project.org/)? (Written in Python, using Gtk. So it doesn't look native on OSX, but works.)

Answer (score 1):

There is [MacPAF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpaf/), but I'm not sure what the status of it is.

Comment: This also hasn't seen activity in over a year

Comment: MacPAF hasn't released any files yet, but I have just heard from the author of cocoa-gedcom that the MacPAF maintainer is contacting developers for a possible relaunch of the project. So that sounds like the most promising option at the moment. 

As a temporary solution, I have found PAW2U, it's not open source but it does the job, until some other product becomes available.
http://www.lanopalera.net/Genealogy/AboutPAWriter.html

Comment: Another proprietary solution is [GEDitCOM](http://www.geditcom.com/)
The trial version reverts to a fully functional read-only interface to a GEDCOM file at the end of the trial period. Still, I'd like to see something (1) open source, (2) with an active community, (3) with read AND write support.

Comment: ... and I have just discovered that there's an objective C iPhone app called [GedView](http://www.ritter.demon.co.uk/Projects/gedview.html) (closed source as well). The developer of GedView has written a GPL application in .NET called [Gedcom.NET](http://www.ritter.demon.co.uk/Projects/gedcom.net.html)(here's the SF project [page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gedcom-net/))

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking into Genealogy-Software, you might want to try the free program "Familienbande".

It's available for Mac and for Windows, free for personal use, supports GedCom and it is well maintained. I only use the German version (the developer is German) but since he has some native speaking US contributors, I assume the English version should also be usable.

The UI needs some getting used to, but for a free program, it is absolutely perfect.

Give it a try under:
http://www.familienbande-genealogie.de/en/index.html

Regards
Thomas